# AS3: EventListener callback overrides function's default parameters?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, callback, event-listener, default-parameters

I discovered encountered something weird today. I have a function with a Boolean default parameter:

```
function f(boolean:Boolean=false) {
    trace(boolean);
}
```

Calling it normally gives what you would expect:

```
f(); //traces false
```

But now if I make my function the callback for an Event Listener, something weird happens:

```
addEventListener("test",f);
dispatchEvent(new Event("test")); //traces true
```

The same thing happens if I make it a callback for clicking on something:

```
mySprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,f); //Traces true on click
```

Can anyone explain what is going on? What is happening to my default value of false? When the event listener calls my function, it's not passing any parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adobe said about the [listener function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener()) :

> ... This function must accept an Event object as its only parameter and must return nothing

So in your case, if you do :

```
function f(boolean:Boolean = false) {
    trace(boolean);
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f);    // gives : true
```

OR

```
var event:MouseEvent = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK);

trace(Boolean(event));                      // gives : true

f(event);                                   // gives : true
```

You will get always the same result : `true`, because every time, your event var pass automatically to your `f` function and converted to `Boolean` and because it's not `null` you will get `true` :

```
trace(Boolean(!null))                       // gives : true
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the listener will use the default parameter. You could use a small inline function to wrap the function you want to get called:

```
function f(boolean:Boolean=false) {
    trace(boolean);
}

addEventListener("test", function(e:Event):void { f() } );
dispatchEvent(new Event("test")); //traces false
```

Answer (score 0):

when u dispatch a event, your listener function would accept parameter from upstream, then the parameter convert to boolean

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @arulmr just Actionscript basic, it's clean for this answer i think.

Comment: This does look like an answer - not a comment.